# How do I use memcpy_toio/fromio?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, memcpy

I am working on a kernel module in C to talk to a PCIe card and I have allocated some io memory using pci_iomap, and I write/read there using ioread/write32.

This works but the performance is quite poor, and I read I could use block transfer through memcpy_toio/fromio instead of just doing 32b at a time.

To write, I am using `iowrite32(buffer[i], privdata->registers + i);`

To read, I do `buffer[i] = ioread32(&privdata->registers[i]);`

I tried to replace the for loops these are in with:

```
memcpy_toio(privdata->registers, buffer, 2048);
memcpy_fromio(buffer, privdata->registers, 2048);
```

If I only replace the write loop with memcpy_toio and I do the reading using ioread32, the program doesn't crash but the instruction doesn't seem to be doing anything (registers don't change);

Also, when I replace the read loop as well with the memcpy_fromio instruction, it crashes.

I was thinking it might be because the reads try to access the mem location while it is still being written to. Is there a way to flush the writes queue after either iowrite32 or memcpy_toio?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Thank you for keeping the details of the crash a secret.

Comment: That's because they are. After I execute the "insmod module_name" command, it stops from responding to anything, including magic SysRq, and all I can do is press the shutdown button. If it helps, I kept a tail -f of /var/log/messages, and it prints all the KERN_INFO messages until the memcpy_toio instruction. It doesn't seem to be kernel panic either, but I don't know where to look for more details after reboot.

Comment: Which architecture? Do the registers implement memory semantics?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by architecture (memory architecture?), or whether memory semantics is relevant for this particular problem. This is just some memory mapped io allocated by overwriting BAR 0 and I should be able to do block transfers to/from there the same as I do 32-bit reads/writes. I just don't know how(what functions, which to use for better performance, how to use them).

Comment: The system architecture (anything under the `arch` directory). Does the BAR set the prefetchable bit?

Comment: It's x86. Not sure about the prefetchable bit though, where do I have to look for this? If it's some code that I would have had to write to modify the default settings, I would guess it's the default value.

Comment: 32-bit, non-prefetchable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memcpy_from/toio()` can be used only if the I/O memory behaves like memory, i.e., if values can be read speculatively, and be written multiple times or out of order.

An I/O range marked as non-prefetchable does not support this.

Comment: Are you aware of how to increase the performance of individual 32-bit reads and writes using the iowrite32/ioread32 ? There should be some functions operating on blocks of memory. The pci-e link bandwidth is up to 2.5Gb and the current performance is much less than 100Mb/s.

Comment: You can't. If the device wanted to be fast, it should have implemented DMA.

Comment: We have a E5-2600 processor where the programmed I/O is much faster than the IOAT DMA (~5GB/s versus ~3GB/s) using ntb_perf as a baseline. It annoys me that this is implemented as a kernel module where figuring out what is actually happening is... involved...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my suggestion is valid, the single ioread32 function is more efficient than memcpy, the read function only needs to read or write the PCI device once, while memcpy needs multiple times. The kernel provides functions such as ioread32_rep to replace the cumbersome for loop (essentially the same).If you need to pursue efficiency, you can try to use ioread32_rep, and you can try to use memcpy for reading and writing of variable length.

Comment: Careful here, ioread32_rep does not increase the IO-Address. It reads the same register over and over again. So it is a different functionality than memcpy_fromio which increases the IO-Address

Answer (score -1):

Which buffer type do you use?

Look at the implementation of [memcpy_fromio()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/frv/include/asm/io.h#L120) , [memcpy_toio()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/frv/include/asm/io.h#L125)

```
 static inline void
 memcpy_fromio(void *dst, volatile void __iomem *src, int count)
 {
        memcpy(dst, (void __force *) src, count);
 }

 static inline void
 memcpy_toio(volatile void __iomem *dst, const void *src, int count)
 {
         memcpy((void __force *) dst, src, count);
 }
```

Yo can see simple memcpy call.

And look at the [iowrite32()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/frv/include/asm/io.h#L333) and [ioread32()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/frv/include/asm/io.h#L309) implementations:

```
static inline void iowrite32(u32 val, void __iomem *p)
 {
         if (__is_PCI_addr(p))
                 val = _swapl(val);
         __builtin_write32(p, val);
         if (__is_PCI_MEM(p))
                 __flush_PCI_writes();
 }

 static inline unsigned int ioread32(void __iomem *p)
 {
         uint32_t ret = __builtin_read32(p);
         if (__is_PCI_addr(p))
                 ret = _swapl(ret);
         return ret;
 }
```

As you can see [memcpy_fromio()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/frv/include/asm/io.h#L120) , [memcpy_toio()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/frv/include/asm/io.h#L125) are not suitable for working with PCIe devices.

Comment: I found that those functions can be used in many sources, but no details on how exactly to use them. For example, http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-9-sect-4 says they can be used as an alternative to ioread/write32 to operate on blocks of io memory. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Please, write part of code, where you try to change registers.

Comment: As per my initial question, I use a for loop with iowrites for those:

for (i = 0; i < 512; i++) {

  iowrite32( (u32) ++c, &privdata->registers[i]);

}

If i then replace this with:
memcpy_toio(privdata->registers, buffer, 2048);
it doesn't do anything. If I also add the read via memcpy_fromio, it crashes.

Comment: Please, write code with variable definition, I don't know, which types do you use. write like as: 
u32 buffer[512];
void* __iomem privdata;
and continue.
Also see, [how to use memcpy_toio() in the kernel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/s390/pci/pci_mmio.c#L67).

Comment: While I applaud digging into the code, memcpy_fromio and memcpy_toio are indeed suitable for working with PCIe devices.  https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.13/driver-api/device-io.html#c.memcpy_fromio

Comment: Except that our E5-2600 processor connected as a PCIe NTB with another E5-2600 processor runs at ~5GB/s with programmed I/O and ~3GB/s with IOAT DMA.