# Can copy_to_user be used for IO memory?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have buffer coming in from the user space which needs to be filled with device registers as a debugging mechanism. Is it safe to use `copy_to_user()` / `copy_from_user()` for device memory? If not, what's the best alternative given that the device driver lies in kernel space?

Comment: No. The API you mentioned has nothing to do with I/O (in terms of PIO, MMIO, DMA).

Comment: Can you suggest the best possible way to copy user buffer into device registers ? I'm currently copying user data into intermediate buffer via copy_from_user / to_user And then doing memory mapped IO to copy into device registers. I feel this is inefficient.

Comment: `memcpy_toio()` and `memcpy_fromio()` is probably what you are looking for.  But note, that they are working solely in the kernel space.

Comment: The accepted answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518336/how-do-i-use-memcpy-toio-fromio tells me that I can't use these APIs for my device. And I'm looking to copy device register to / from user-space.

Comment: Don't believe everything on SO, more rating person has, more garbish the answer is... :-( There are two answers and both wrong if you think about MMIO case.

Comment: Thanks for the help. For now, I'm going to copy user buffer into a kernel buffer via copy_from_user, And then do memcpy_to_io from that kernel buffer to the device memory (vice versa for transferring data to user from device). Though this is somewhat inefficient, it does the job for me. I'm not sure if it is valuable enough to add an API in the kernel which copies userspace data directly to device ? Guess not many people need this functionality anyway.

Comment: There is an API called UIO (User-space I/O). It does help with cases like this. But rather you should do DMA, if you consider it's way too slow.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58434424/5264491) of mine might help.

Answer (score 0):

All the comments are wrong.

1. For any data moves between user and kernel spaces, you **have** to use `copy_from/to_user`
2. `memcpy_from/toio()` are reserved for addresses IN the kernel space and MMIO. It's unsafe to use those functions with user-space addresses.

### Answer:

You can simply use `copy_from/to_user()` directly with the mapped MMIO address in `void * to` or `void * from`. So that you don't need a useless intermediate buffer.

To be used only with prefetchable memory since it might read/write several times the same memory and/or in an unordered way.